# Query a stored procedure that exec's a dynamic query. Error Linked server indicates object has no columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that dynamically creates a pivot query.

The procedure works and returns the correct data.

Now I have a requirement to show this data in a reporting system that can only pull from a table or view.  Since you can not create a dynamic query in a view I tried to do a select from using openquery.

Example '

> Select * from OpenQuery([MyServername], 'Exec
>   Instance.Schema.StoredProcedure')

I get the error back

> "the linked server indicates the object has no columns".

I assume this is because of the first select statement that is stuffing the variable with column names.

CODE FROM PROCEDURE

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FuelCombustorMatrix]


AS
BEGIN
-- Use Master

SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @cols nvarchar(2000),
        @Tcols nvarchar(2000),
        @Sql nvarchar (max)

select @cols = stuff ((
                        Select distinct '], ['+ModelName + '  ' + CombustorName
                            from CombustorFuel cf
                            join Model m on cf.modelid = m.modelid
                            join Combustors cb on cf.CombustorID = cb.CombustorID
                            where cf.CombustorID > 0
                            for XML Path('')
                        ),1,2,'')+']'

Set @Tcols = replace(@Cols, ']', '] int')
--Print @Tcols          
--Print @Cols

Set @Sql = 'Select GasLiquid, FuelType, '+ @Cols +'
from 
    (
    Select GasLiquid, FuelType, ModelName+ ''  '' +CombustorName ModelCombustor, CombFuelStatus+''- ''+CombFuelNote CombFuelStatusNote
        from Frames f
        join Family fa on f.Frameid = fa.frameid
        join Model m on fa.FamilyID = m.FamilyID
        join CombustorFuel cf on m.Modelid = cf.modelid
        Join Combustors c on cf.CombustorId = c.CombustorID
        join FuelTypes ft on cf.FuelTypeID = ft.FuelTypeID
        where cf.CombustorFuelID > 0
          and CombustorName <> ''''
    ) up
Pivot 
    (max(CombFuelStatusNote) for ModelCombustor in ('+ @Cols +')) as pvt
order by FuelType'

exec (@Sql)

END
```

Comment: please share more detail like what is the output of query without pivoting and what format you want this to be appeared in report?

Comment: Well I tried to add some example data but it would format right and I lost all the formatting of the code.  But the data is not important.  How can I pull the results from the stored procedure into a view.  That is easy for any store procedure but this one creates a dynamic select statement.